# Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Close' in Powershell v4.0

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

this is my first StackOverflow question, but I will try to keep the community standards in mind..

I am running Office 2013 on Win7 Pro and PoSh v4.0. Upon execution of the subsequent script, I receive the following error: **"Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Close'."**

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $false
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false
$filepath = "C:\Users\rysullivan\Desktop\Projects\EDCautomation\attach\"
$wb1 = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Join-Path $filepath "Ryan Sullivan-Template.xlsx"))
sleep 5
$wb1.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
```

In keeping with the standard of presenting the shortest code that will reproduce the error, I developed the above code down from a larger automation

[Powershell 4.0 and Excel 2013 | Bug | Work-a-round](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325785/powershell-4-0-and-excel-2013-bug-work-a-round)  seemed to be getting at the same point. I followed the thread/culture solution offered by XXInvidiaXX and the same error was generated.

[Problems with Excel automation in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458852/problems-with-excel-automation-in-powershell)  had an answer by Roy that pointed to a timing error, but I inserted a Sleep command and tried running the open and close commands separately, both to no avail.

Any help, especially underlying theory, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: wouldnt it be `$wb1.close()`?

Comment: Dane, Thanks for getting back so quickly. I originally had $wb1.Close() and was testing things out. I forgot to change it back. I have updated the heading/question.

Comment: I am using Win8.1 instead of Win7 but I am unable to replicate the error. I created the 'Projects\EDCautomation\attach' path on my desktop, created a blank workbook at that location named 'Ryan Sullican-Template.xlsx', changed the beginning of the path string to `$env:USERPROFILE`, and ran the script without issues. Could this be workbook related with something weird in your file? Maybe close PS or reboot and try again to make sure it's not something stuck in memory?

Comment: [All examples on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8yh918.aspx) specify the first optional argument at minimum. Maybe try `$wb1.Close($false)` or `$wb1.Close($false,$null,$false)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Thank you, $wb1.Close($false) seems to have worked for me. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen If you'd like credit and to tie the page off, submit that as an answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the arguments to [`Workbook.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.close.aspx) are all optional, [all the examples on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8yh918.aspx) provide at least one (the **SaveChanges** argument), leading me to believe that PowerShell does not recognize the method signature when you don't provide any arguments.

You might have better luck with:

```
$wb1.Close($false)
```

or

```
$wb1.Close($false,$null,$null)
```

Substitute with `$true` to save any changes you may have made

Comment: Adding $false solves similar issue with $OfficeObject.Quit() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a method of `Quit()` at the level of the Excel process (`$xl` in this case), rather than the workbook (`$wb1`).

So using your code, it would be written as follows (with `$xl.Quit()` instead of `$wb1.Close()`):

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $false
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false
$filepath = "C:\Users\rysullivan\Desktop\Projects\EDCautomation\attach\"
$wb1 = $xl.Workbooks.Open((Join-Path $filepath "Ryan Sullivan-Template.xlsx"))
sleep 5
$xl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
```

Also be sure to run it as administrator.

Comment: As a sidenote, I'd also declare your username through `[Environment]::UserName` in order to make your script more portable - set it to a variable (such as `$user`) and then use that in the middle of the filepath. It'll then look for the Desktop folder of whomever is running the script. It's not necessarily relevant for this project, but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: I'm getting `Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Quit'.`

Comment: @HackSlash - what version of Powershell are you running, and are you running it as administrator?

Comment: 5.1.18362.628 and yes